# UI View too big

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I created a project to make IPhone Application. Then I follow instruction on '
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/05_ConfiguringView.html

Well I make my first UIViewController but what I got seems to be an UI View Controller for iPad

Its too big

I want to create things for iPhone. Not iPad.

So what to do?

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating a new `UIViewController` uncheck the "Target for ipad" radio button option.